# How to scann using RedLaser library and return barcode to ScanBarcodeActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, barcode-scanner

I am using RedLaser library to scan barcode for product. My class extends after BarcodeScanActivity. Method **onScanStatusUpdate** is used to getting barcode without break. When I am saving barcode to db, it is saving one barcode in loop. I am scanning barcode and saving it to db on one activity. How can I pause **onScanStatusUpdate** method, and resume it after I will move to next barcode?

Comment: did you get a soultion for this?

Comment: I used the STATUS_NEW_FOUND_BARCODES and I can add X product per One barcode